# Google map not displaying in play store apk

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I know there are already few questions on the topic.
But I have done all suggested by people. But still the apk from play store doesn't display the map and it shows just a white background, though map is displayed when I launch app form android studio into my android phone.

I want to know whether we need to put the following in manifest file:

```
 <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
 <permission
android:name="com.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

Its not there currently in manifest file.

PS:I upload apk on play store in beta test mode.

Answer (score 0):

Does your debug APK shows correctly? Then, have you registered your production keystore hash correctly? Remember that in the Google's API console you need to register the hashes of your debug and production keys. Also, the "com.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" permission isn't necessary.

Comment: Debug apk works fine. When I added the map feature in AS, google_maps_api.xml is created,debug and release version. Key is there in debug one while release version doesn't have the key. So I created the signed apk and uploaded on store. And when I downloaded apk, i realised the issue. Then looking into debug xml, I saw the steps mentioned to generate key on google developer console which I followed and got key generated which then I placed in release version of the xml, and made changes in build.gradle to pick debug and release value as per the build.Uploaded release apk, but still same issue.

Comment: Do you created two API keys? One for debug and one for production? It's not necessary I think, but it should work anyway. If you go that way (two keys) then you should register the hash of the debug keystore in the debug API key entrance and the hash of the production keystore in the production API key entrance of the Google's API console. If you are using the same API key for both debug and production, then you should register both the debug and production keystore hashes in that key entrance in the Google's API console.

Comment: Beware that when you run your app the Google maps library checks your key with the Google's servers. If the hashes doesn't match then it rejects you, so you will see a white background in place of the map. That's the reason I think you have a hash - API key registration issue in your production flavor.

Comment: I think issue is that I followed the steps in google_maps_api.xml(debug).I should rather follow steps in google_maps_api.xml(release).Not sure though. And strange thing is that I have map integrated in one of my other android app and it works fine everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean in "I saw the steps mentioned to generate key on google developer console"? Do you refer to the API key or the keystore hash? Remember that you need to use your debug keystore hash with the debug API key and the production keystore hash with the production API key (or register both production and debug hashes with the same API key if you are using the same API key for production and debug releases).

Comment: In google_maps_api.xml, they provide a link(which carries SHA finger print and package name) which developer needs to copy in browser, and it takes you to the developer console where you follow some steps and press create button, and you get your key. Thats what i did. But I copies link from debug version of google_maps_api.xml. I think I need to copy link from release version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115781/discussion-between-josemgu91-and-mandroid).

Comment: same problem here. It works in my local, both in debug and release, but when downloading from Play Store, maps are not rendering. The only thing I can guess is that, as is new app its package name, it has not been yet propagated to google's servers..... so I will wait for a while. But, not clue really what is the difference between my local release and the one downloaded from Play. (???)